# Facebook insights via graph.facebook.com authentication flow

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I am trying to programatically grab a few insights metrics from facebook for various pages (about 50 clients). Therefore I want to automate this.

I created a facebook app and have my `app_id` and `app_secret`. I also created a `app_access_token` which doesn't expire?

My question is this: How do I get the `page access token` for each of the pages I want to get insights from? Currently I...

STEP 1) ...went to the `Query Explorer` and seleted my app and grabbed a `user_access` token with the `manage_pages` and `read_insights` permissions.

STEP 2) I then used that `user_access_token` to go to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{pagename}?fields=access_token&access_token={user_access_token}` to get what I presume is the `page_access_token`.

STEP 3) I then use this token to do my queries for things like `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{pagename}/insights/page_impressions?access_token={page_access_token}`.

Now since the app is already OKAYed, shouldn't be there a way to grab that `user_access_token` in step 1 programatically? They all expire except the `app_access_token` I described above. Can I use that token somehow in step 1?

I am not using and SDKs just pure https calls.

Comment: No there is no way to get a user access token without the user manually doing things

Comment: There is no way to achieve this without using a SDK. Please go through this:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is possible. I managed to get an extended page access token by doing this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=[app-id]&client_secret=[app-secret]&fb_exchange_token=[short-lived-token]
```

from [here](http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/). Basically you get a short lived user token and then use that to get a page access token and then use that with your app id/secret to get an extended page token that never expires (perfect for embedding in an automated reporting app).

It is convoluted but it works. And as a bonus if you register the APP on Facebook business manager, that page token will work on all sites you have access to under that business manager account.